# System.ArgumentNullException when creating a new Silverlight Project

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, xaml, designer

I'm getting the exception listed below when looking at the MainPage.xaml of a newly created Silverlight application. By newly created I mean nothing, at all, has been modified; I just create the solution in VS and get the error as soon as it loads the xaml in the designer.

- I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional on Windows XP.
- Building the entire solution succeeds and appears to run without error. I say "appears" though because it's a blank screen; no controls have been added.
- I've recreated the solution multiple times, restarted VS, rebooted, etc.
- I've tried running the repair/reinstall twice.
- I've applied all updates available via Windows Update.
- I've tried creating both Silverlight 3 and 4 solutions.
- I've searched the Internet to no avail.

What's wrong?

```
System.ArgumentNullException
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: parentContext
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.ReflectionMetadataContext..ctor(IMetadataContext parentContext)
   at MS.Internal.Host.ProjectMetadataContext..ctor(IMetadataContext platformMetadata, AssemblyReferenceProvider referenceProvider)
   at MS.Internal.Host.ProjectMetadataContext.FromReferences(AssemblyReferenceProvider referenceProvider)
   at MS.Internal.Designer.VSDesigner.GetMetadataForDesignerContext(DesignerContext designerContext)
   at MS.Internal.Host.PersistenceSubsystem.Load()
   at MS.Internal.Host.Designer.Load()
   at MS.Internal.Designer.VSDesigner.Load()
   at MS.Internal.Designer.VSIsolatedDesigner.VSIsolatedView.Load()
   at MS.Internal.Designer.VSIsolatedDesigner.VSIsolatedDesignerFactory.Load(IsolatedView view)
   at MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.BootstrapProxy.LoadDesigner(IsolatedDesignerFactory factory, IsolatedView view)
   at MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.BootstrapProxy.LoadDesigner(IsolatedDesignerFactory factory, IsolatedView view)
   at MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.Load()
   at MS.Internal.Designer.DesignerPane.LoadDesignerView()
```

Comment: Try disabling any extensions you may have installed by going to Tools -> Extension Manager.

Comment: In the extension manager all I see is "There are no extensions installed."

Comment: I foolishly tried to uninstall XNA, Silverlight, basically anything that had to do with Windows Phone, in order to do a 'fresh install', and then started having this problem.  Now my "solution" is to not use the graphical XAML designer in VS, but instead to use Expression Blend.  I know this is not a solution, but I've scoured the internet like you have and I really don't think there is a solution (other than the ultimate one of blowing away your OS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up having to reinstall Windows, unfortunate, but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Silverlight Developer runtime installed ?

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=146060

Comment: I'm able to build and run the project, so, yes, I do believe so.

Comment: Reinstalled just to be sure, no change.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is getting this error when making a new Windows Phone project (which uses Silverlight), if you install the Windows Phone SDK 7.1 (or probably any SDK after that), it should fix this problem.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27570

I didn't have to uninstall anything before this install.  Just download the vm_web2.exe, and run it.  Reopen VS, make a brand new Windows Phone project, everything should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall all the silverlight SDK and toolkit, and reinstall silverlight 4 toolkit. Do not have to install Silverlight 3 again. It fix my problem.